# Magento cache lite.php error

Tags: php, magento, caching, magento-1.9

After uploading website on server website is half loading [website](http://splind.in/)

When i checked system log file I found this

> 2016-02-26T08:14:25+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Cache/Lite.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/splind/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
>   2016-02-26T08:14:25+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Cache/Lite.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/splind/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
>   2016-02-26T08:14:25+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Cache/Lite.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/splind/public_html/app/code/local:/home/splind/public_html/app/code/community:/home/splind/public_html/app/code/core:/home/splind/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/splind/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

Comment: Have you tried deleting everything inside `/var/cache` folder?

Comment: This is a problem with your cache definition in local.xml, it cannot find the class used for the cache backend. Can you post your full cache config?

Comment: Bit old post, but I got this same issue. What caused it ?